# How to show a specific child component depending of the props provided in the parents component in VueJS

Tags: vue-component

i want to call(nest) a specific component in another one given the value of a prop in the parent component.
I have two type of buttons that i use, my problem is that i want to be able to use one of them depending of the prop given in the parent component.
like, if i give the prop the value 'b', then the first button will be render in my component, if not then the other button.

Each button being a component, i use

```
    <component :is='componentname'/>
```

so my problem is that i want to be able to change the value of 'componentname' depending of the value of the prop of the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

ok. problem solved.
i could access the prop value using "this.propname" or "this.$props.propname" and then using "coomputed" to update the value of component name.

```
    <template>
    <div 
    class="sidebar-item" 
    :text="text"
    :symbole="symbole"
    :type='type'
    >
        <component :is="componentName"/>
        <p>
            {{text}}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import SideBarButton from './SideBarButton';
import SideBarListButton from './SideBarListButton';
export default {
    components:{
        SideBarButton,
        SideBarListButton,
    },
    props:[
        'text',
        'symbole',
        'type'
    ],
    data(){
        return{
           options:false, 
        }
    },
    computed:{
        componentName() {
            if(this.$props.type == 'b'){
                return 'side-bar-list-button'
            }else{
                return 'side-bar-button'
            }
        }
    },
    provide(){
        return{
            symbole : this.symbole
        }
    },
}
</script>
```